# Kotlin/native compiler can't functions inet_addr, htons, e.t.c

Tags: kotlin-native

I would like to write simple program with socket connection in kotlin/native:

There is simple function that open and bind socket.

```
actual fun openSocket(endpoint: IpPort): Socket {
    // Initialize sockets in platform-dependent way.
    init_sockets()
    var socketDescriptor = 0
    memScoped {
        val serverAddr = alloc<sockaddr_in>()
        socketDescriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
            .ensureUnixCallResult("socket") { !it.isMinusOne() }
        with(serverAddr) {
            memset(this.ptr, 0, sockaddr_in.size.narrow())
            sin_family = AF_INET.convert()
            sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(endpoint.cstr.ptr); /
            //sin_port = htons(endpoint.port.convert()) 
        }
        bind(socketDescriptor, serverAddr.ptr.reinterpret(), sockaddr_in.size.convert())
            .ensureUnixCallResult("bind") { it == 0 }
    }
    return Socket(socketDescriptor)
}
```

Compiler (./gradlew compileKonan) can't resolve functions: `inet_addr`, `htons`.
Also compiler resolver import `import platform.ios.*`.
I think these function should be on iOS system (and any other OS) headers.

There is `build.gradle` of

```
apply plugin: 'konan'

konan.targets = ['iphone']

konanArtifacts {
    framework('MezzoCore') {
        enableMultiplatform true   
    }
}

dependencies {
    expectedBy project(':common')
}
```

I can't understand what i do wrong. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Following may help:

```
import platform.posix.*
import platform.darwin.*
import kotlinx.cinterop.*

// Just to avoid import conflict.
typealias sockaddr_in = platform.posix.sockaddr_in

fun main() {
   val endpoint ="127.0.0.1"
   val port = 8080
   var socketDescriptor = 0
   memScoped {
       val serverAddr = alloc<sockaddr_in>()
       socketDescriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
       with(serverAddr) {
           memset(this.ptr, 0, sockaddr_in.size.convert())
           sin_family = AF_INET.convert()
           sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(endpoint)
           sin_port = ((port shr 8) or ((port and 0xff) shl 8)).toUShort()
        }
        bind(socketDescriptor, serverAddr.ptr.reinterpret(), 
                 sockaddr_in.size.convert())
     }
     println("sd=$socketDescriptor")   
}
```

Comment: i had found solution: i created *.def file and added `interop_htons()` and `interop_htons()` function. It works on iOS and MacOS

Comment: @PavelSantaev could you share an example on how to define these functions in the def file, please?

Comment: @ThomasVos
headers = sys/socket.h sys/errno.h netdb.h stdio.h string.h unistd.h stdlib.h netinet/in.h sys/_endian.h arpa/inet.h
compilerOpts.ios = -D_ANSI_SOURCE -D_POSIX_SOURCE
compilerOpts.osx = -D_ANSI_SOURCE -D_POSIX_SOURCE
---

static int interop_errno() {
        return errno;
}

static short interop_htons(short x) {
 return htons(x);
}

static in_addr_t interop_addr(const char *str) {
 return inet_addr(str);
}